# What is the name of this kind of Java/Swing interface?

Tags: java, swing

Do you  know what is the name of this layout for Java/Swing? Does the Java library already bring us this or should I do that on my own? If so, could any one of you  show some samples?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the sample code for a [Dual JList](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DualJList.htm).  This is not a primitive Swing construct, but something you can build using Swing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not provided by the Java swing library - you would have to roll your own or find a 3rd-party library.

Comment: If its a webapp, you can easily create this using Javascript and HTML.

Comment: You can easily create one with Swing.

Comment: Do a google on Javascript Dual List, you will find tons of examples.

Comment: I didn't say that you couldn't - I just said that writing a component was not complicated

Answer (score 1):

The commercial [JIDE Grids](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm) has a `DualList` (scroll to page bottom for a screenshot).

Generally it's not easy to create a really solid Swing widget. You don't have to use custom UI for DualList, but it still takes a lot of work to get the MVC and UI (under all current LAFs) all working well.

Currently JIDE DualList doesn't support drag-n-drop between the lists, but they promised to add it soon (you can search their forum for DualList if you're a paying customer).

Answer (score 0):

I think that GridBagLayout is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have 3 JPanels: 
the first and third are the blank panes and the one in the middle contains two JButtons. GridBagLayout will be a good choice here.

You would want to add some ActionListeners to the two buttons in the middle to control the behaviour.